# How connect a client to a remote Windows Server 2019 AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server

We have a very difficult problem here, we have a Windows Server 2019 Base x64 on Amazon EC2, connected through RDP and setup-ed forest and activated AD DS , also activated DNS. But whenever we try to connect we are not allowed to.

We have opened all the relevant ports on inbound traffic rules.
We have added users.
We have tried searching internet and various tutorials.
In Server Manager=:
Added the public ipv4 address to our ipv4 settings of the adapter.
Went to the computer setting in computer domain entered the domain but no fun.
Disabled the firewall in server manager.

**We want to connect our clients on different network to connect to the server hosted else-where on AWS.**

We are really new into this can some one guide through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure there is network connectivity between your client and you DC which is set up on EC-2 Instance.

> > [1] In case your clients are on AWS (meaning different EC-2 Instances), and in a different network, you need to create VPC peering or use Transit Gateway, so that it has proper network connectivity.
> >
> > [2] In case your clients are not on AWS, and in an On-prem Environment, you need to have a VPN connection between your client and your DC.

So in Summary, you need to have network connectivity between your client and DC so that clients can join your Domain.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean whenever we try to connect we are not allowed to?
What are you trying to connect to, the Windows EC2 instance?

Are you saying that the instance is joined to AWS Directory Service domain but you can't connect to the instance using one of the users in your AWS directory?

Edit: This should have been a comment but couldn't post comments at the time of answering.